# Canvas with coordinates geography

Tags: javascript, html

I need to draw on a canvas and then send the point as geographic coordinates (latitude, longitude). Is there a Canvas for this?  I need the background of the canvas to be white, so I need something different than a Map.

Answer (score 0):

You need to improve the way your question is worded. If you use Google Maps API, you can use overlays to show any information over the map, which could have the white background you need.

Check https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays